# Selection of table values based on record

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have three tables with the following structure:

```
Table1:    Cat  
Fields:    Cat0 Cat1
Record 1:   A   
Record 2:   B   
Record 3:   C   
Record 4:   D   

Table2:    CatB
Fields:    Option
Record 1:   X
Record 2:   Y

Table3:    CatD
Fields:    Option
Record 1:   1
Record 2:   2
```

Cat1 should lookup to CatB, if Cat0 has B in its record
Cat1 should lookup to CatD, if Cat0 has D in its record

The Output expected is:

```
Table1:    Cat  
Fields:    Cat0 Cat1
Record 1:   A   NULL
Record 2:   B   X or Y (Combo box)
Record 3:   C   NULL
Record 4:   D   1 or 2 (Combo box)
```

I am using lookup values in MS Access.

The following code doesn't work in the lookup of Cat1:

```
SELECT * 
FROM Cat a 
INNER JOIN CatB b on b.Option = a.Cat0 
WHERE a.Cat0 = "B" 
UNION SELECT * 
FROM Cat a 
INNER JOIN CatD d on d.Option = a.Cat0 
WHERE a.Cat0 = "D";
```

How can this be achieved?

Thanks.

Comment: Cat has two fields but you only give one value per row. "Cat1 to have a lookup option of CatB, if Cat0 has B, and, Cat1 to have a lookup option of CatD, if Cat0 has D in it" is unclear. Please use enough sentences to say what you mean. Use simple sentences. Clearly refer to parts of things. Try google translate. Please read & act on [mcve].

Comment: Edit your question and show the results that you want.

Comment: Are you looking for a lookup field in a table, or in a form? Because options for lookups in tables are really limited.

Answer (score 0):

I NEVER set lookups in table, only on forms.

Correct UNION statement in a query named Options:

```
SELECT "B" As Cat, Option FROM CatB
UNION SELECT "D", Option FROM CatD;
```

Instead of having to resort to UNION, why don't you have a single table for the CatB and CatD options.

```
Table:     Options
Fields:    Cat, Option
Record 1:   B,   X
Record 2:   B,   Y
Record 3:   D,   1
Record 4:   D,   2
```

In either case, combobox can have conditional SQL statement in RowSource.
`SELECT Option FROM Options WHERE Cat=[Cat0];`

If you want to stick with UNION and use all-in-one statement for RowSource:

```
SELECT Option FROM (SELECT "B" As Cat, Option FROM CatB
UNION SELECT "D", Option FROM CatD) AS Options WHERE Cat=[Cat0];
```

And code in Cat1 GotFocus event: `Me.Cat1.Requery`.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion and response. I don't have complex needs for my database and want to use a simple SharePoint + Access solution. So lookups in Access DB fields are fine.

Comment: I tried 'SELECT Option FROM Options WHERE Cat=[Cat0];' on the single Options table with CatB and CatD consolidated, but Cat.Cat1 shows no values. Any advice?

Comment: You tried that as the lookup RowSource? Does the dropdown list show items?